# Confirm box on drag and release opens duplicate confirm box in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, internet-explorer-11

I have a confirm box created using javascript code given below. After getting confirm box if I drag it using mouse and leave it then it opens a new confirm box with previous one also open in IE11. Therefore doing so continuously opens so many confirm box. But it works fine in IE8.Please suggest how to deal with this issue. Is it a bug in IE11 ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a     confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}            
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTM    L = txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in your IE.

Answer (score 0):

See if your issue occurs while using this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhoy65cb/)? if it does then it is most likely a bug in your specific version of IE:

```
function func() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```